# Drawing paths on pdf files, using jagPDF in C++

Tags: c++, pdf-generation

I have a question that shouldn't be too difficult to answer but I am very new to C++ and have not been able to figure it out.

I am using [JAGPDF](http://www.jagpdf.org/) in order to create a pdf file that shows the output of my C++ program. Using JagPDF I am trying to simply draw a rectangle following their instructions. Unfortunately their examples are made in Python and a little "translation" is needed. The code in python is

```
canvas.rectangle(50, 400, 500, 350)
canvas.path_paint('s')
```

the path_paint function in C++ is defined as:

```
void path_paint(Char const* cmd);
```

According to the guide, cmd is specified by a string comprising of a meaningful combination of the following letters:

```
's' stroke
'f' fill - nonzero winding
'F' fill - even odd
'c' close
'w' clip - nonzero winding
'W' clip - even odd
```

I tried doing something like this

```
char cmd = 's';
char const* ptr = &cmd;
doc.page().canvas().path_paint(ptr);
```

but is giving me errors. How can I call that function correctly? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Did you try reading the errors?  Have you considered actually posting them as part of your question?

Comment: sorry is not an error it is throwing an exception, as if the input of the function is wrong. So it's not giving me an error message just something like "Unhandled exception at 0x770196C2 in PDF.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: jag::pdf::Exception at memory location 0x00F8D308." so no much help from there

Comment: Without looking at the API to see whether you're invoking `path_paint` correctly, I will just point out that you have not given it a string and so you have undefined behaviour.  Pass an actual (null-terminated) string, not a pointer to a char like this: `path_paint( "s" )`

Comment: Thank you Paddy, I was using single quotes instead of double ones inside the parenthesis. With the double quotes worked just fine. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

That subject is good documented in Section Text:

```
doc.page().canvas().text(50, 760, "Text");
```

or using font:

```
Canvas canvas = doc.page().canvas();
canvas.text_start(20, 420);
canvas.text_font(font);
canvas.text("Text");
canvas.text_translate_line(0, font.height());
```